# How to use the angular material 2 docs offline?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I would like to use the [documentation of Angular Material 2](http://material.angular.io) offline. What options do i have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular Material's docs are bundled up with the source code. For each component, you'll find commented, clean code, a markdown file, tests, and examples. The documentation is actually built from the source.

> What options do I have?

*Option 1: Download the source.*

It's an open source project, so you can go to [the project on Github](https://github.com/angular/material2) and download it there. If you go to a given component in `src/lib`, all the information is right there in the comments.

*Option 2: Go look at the source code in your `node_modules` (Requires Typescript support in your editor of choice and Material in your project)*

Since the project uses Typescript, you can probably just Ctrl + Click on the component (or some other shortcut) to get to the source file for that component. In that source file, you'll see all the relevant comments and code for that component (just like option 1).

I find the code / comments more informative than the online version.

Answer (score 1):

clone the official repository for the angular material doc

`git clone https://github.com/angular/material2.git`

change path to project root

```
cd material.anular.io
```

install dependencies

```
 npm install
```

finally run it on your machine

```
 ng serve
```